# Python and terminal - Strings with special characters

Tags: python

I know the Python thing that if I'm using interactive interpreter and I write `'\\ '` it prints `'\\ '` but if if I write `print '\\ '` it prints `'\ '`.

What I'm trying to do is (in a script called `p.py`):

```
import os
os.system('echo ' + 'string with spaces'.replace(' ', '\ '))
```

obviously it won't let me do this. I mean, Python manages to add TWO backslashes instead of one but I think it does so only in interactive mode, but the terminal, when passed special chars like `\`, ignores them.

So that, as the output of the provious code, I get:

```
local:$ string with spaces
```

and not

```
local:$ string\ with\ spaces
```

I already tried hardcoded strings and everything else in Python, but I guess the problem is with shell strings.

How could I solve this?

It it can help to find alteratives solutions, what I'm trying to do is moving a file from python with the `mv` command, and this file has spaces in its name.

Comment: Just curious, why are you trying to use backslashes?

The shell uses quotes note backslashes to not treat spaces as special.  For example echo "string with spaces".  I feel like I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

```
os.system('echo ' + 'string with spaces'.replace(' ', '\ '))
```

In that line, the last string `'\ '` will try to escape a space, even though that is not an escape sequence. If you want it to become a space with a preceding backspace, you can either escape the backspace (`'\\ '`), or you can use a raw string which will ignore all escape sequences (`r'\ '`).